# Why did a subdomain from a trusted website download a file?

Tags: web

I clicked on a link for the subdomain of a trusted website (the subdomain slackin.brilliant.org of the website brilliant.org), and instead of being directed to another page, a file called "download" simply downloaded onto my computer. I deleted the file right away, so I don't know its contents, but I  was worried that maybe the file had malicious contents (could Brilliant.org maybe own a domain and not have control of this subdomain, therefore allowing perpetrators of malware to capitalize on this?).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing malicious is going on. The file is empty.

This happens when there is a misconfiguration of the webserver and instead of serving a page to display, it transfers the target as a file. In this case, there was nothing to transfer.

This sort of thing was a lot more common in the early days of the web, but I'm shocked to see it these days.

Comment: What was the MIME type?

Comment: no MIME type - empty - 0 bytes

Comment: (@Daisetsu) for me, Content-Type is application/octet-stream which admittedly is often used to mean 'I haven't got a clue'. (And yes Content-Length 0.)